# Proving arguments are valid using rules of inference.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

Use the rules of inference and the laws of propositional logic to prove that each argument is valid. Number each line of your argument and label each line of your proof "Hypothesis" or with the name of the rule of inference used at that line. If a rule of inference is used, then include the numbers of the previous lines to which the rule is applied.

p → (q ∧ r)

¬q

∴ ¬p

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have with this?

Comment: So this is another example that has a solution. The solution to the one in my post should look similar to this solution.                                         
p → q

q → r

¬r

∴ ¬p

Solution

1. q → r Hypothesis
2. p → q Hypothesis
3. p → r Hypothetical syllogism, 1, 2
4. ¬r         Hypothesis
5. ¬p         Modus tollens, 3, 4

Comment: The form you need is an *argument by contradiction*.

Comment: @GrahamKemp The system could have a rule of inference which says ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\land$$\gamma$)) $\vdash$ (($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$)$\land$($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$)).  It could also allow conjunction elimination and clausification.  If it has a rule of resolution also, no argument by contradiction would be needed to solve this.  This also suggests why we should know all the permissible rules of inference first.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions seem clear enough.   Construct a table like so and then fill in the missing details.$${\begin{array}{r|l:l}1 & p\to(q\wedge r) & \text{Premise 1 (Hypothesis)}\\ 2 & \neg q & \text{Premise 2 (Hypothesis)}\\\hdashline 3 & \quad p& \text{Assumption (Hypothesis)}\\ \vdots & \quad \vdots& \vdots\\ \underline\quad & \quad \bot& \underline{\quad},\underline{\quad},\textit{rule of inference}\\ \underline\quad & \neg p & 3,\underline\quad,\text{Hypothesis negation}\\ \hline\end{array}\\ \therefore\quad p\to(q\wedge r), \neg q \vdash \neg p}$$

Comment: What would be the steps between p and ¬p then?